# How to access Mongodb in ec2 instance using lambda in vpc setup?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

In security group(inbound rules) of ec2 instance i have opened mongo port to security group of lambda function
[EC2 inbound rules screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbnVH.png)

In lambda function also i have selected vpc,subnets and security group.
[Lambda vpc configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUUM.png)

Also i have configured NAT gateway for vpc.
Still i am not able to access mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the `subnets` in your VPC (which is used by your lambda function) to the `security group`.

e.g.

[image]

but in this case, change the `3306` to mongodb port e.g. `27017`